# How can selenium start chrome hidden in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

How can selenium start chrome  hidden in vb.net?

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        driverS = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService
        driverS.HideCommandPromptWindow = True
        driverO = New ChromeOptions
        driverO.AddArgument("--incognito")
        driverO.AddArgument("--disable-extensions")

        driver = New ChromeDriver(driverS, driverO)

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hidden as in headless? If you're running Chrome on version 60 or higher you can add the argument 'headless'

```
driverO.AddArgument("headless")
```

Comment: OMG, Thanks!!  and you know how to minimumized?

Comment: I don’t know for sure with VB.Net, but it’s something like `driver0.Manage().Window.Minimize()`. Syntax could be a bit different, I’m on my phone right now so can’t check it

Comment: i was driverO.Manage().Window.Minimize(), but not play. Thanks very much!